# Is assigning size_t (larger than int range) to int UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

On Linux x86_64:

```
size_t some_constant = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
int my_int = some_constant;
size_t my_size_t = my_int;
cout << (my_size_t == some_constant) << endl;
```

this prints `1`

Is this an example of UB?

Answer (score 4):

Not undefined, just implementation defined.

> **[conv.integral]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#3) If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be
>   represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is
>   implementation-defined.

So whatever your implementation of C++ does, it must document it somehow. Which also makes it far more likely that it won't break suddenly, because implementers usually like to keep documented behavior unchanged.